# How do you do Auth with AuthenticationFilter and RequestContext?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, requestcontext

We're building a GWT+hibernate+spring web app that's deployed to tomcat and postgres. Looking at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ and http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Hashing_Java#Complete_Java_Sample, We have a User table and a Role table(4-5 roles, to start with).

Various layers of the app need access to the currently logged in user's info(like loginId, locale, etc), so I'm thinking of adding a AuthenticationFilter which will authenticate each Http request and create a ThreadLocal RequestContext which will hold various user attributes.

I'm also thinking of having a AuthCache which will store a ConcurrentHashMap of sessionIds and loginIds. AuthenticationFilter will use the AuthCache for Authentication.

I understand Spring security and Apache Shiro(http://incubator.apache.org/projects/shiro.html) are probably better ways but I have very little time to get this done so skipping for now.

**Just wanted to know if there are better ways to do this ? Is there existing code which does this right so my implementation doesn't have many holes ?**

Answer (score 0):

> Just wanted to know if there are better ways to do this ? Is there existing code which does this right so my implementation doesn't have many holes?

This is probably not the expected answer but, what about Spring Security? Spring Security requires some efforts but

- it just works
- it is widely used
- it is very likely more secure than a custom development

And I'm not convinced that a custom development will take less time than integrating Spring Security.

Just in case you'd like to reconsider this option, here is  little tutorial. Worth the read IMO.

- [Spring Security - Tutorial: Adding Security to Spring Petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks Pascal -- I have about 6 hours to do this -- so, can't afford to do Spring Security.

Comment: however, I invite your comments on my above proposed design. thank you.

Comment: @anjab 6 hours are extremely short indeed. Will update answer then.